# Dual Vector Spaces - Evaluation at a Point of a Polynomial Gives a Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, duality-theorems

My question is the following:

Let $\{a_0,a_1,...,a_n\}$ be (pairwise) distinct, real numbers. Let $V$ be the vector spaces of all polynomials of degree at most $n$, ie $V = \Bbb P_n$. Let $\phi_j : V^* \rightarrow \Bbb R$ ($V^*$ is the dual basis of $V$) be given by $\phi_j(p) = p(a_j)$.

My question is to show that $\{\phi_1, \phi_2, ..., \phi_n\}$ forms a basis for $V^*$. So far, it boils down to showing that, given $\{\nu_1,...,\nu_n\}$,
$$\sum_{j=0}^n \nu_j a_j^r = 0 \ \ \ \text{for} \ r = 0, 1, ..., n
\\ \Rightarrow \nu_j = 0 \ \ \ \text{for all $j$}. $$
The issue is that we have, for example, $1^2 = (-1)^2$, so when trying to show the matrix $M = (M_{ij})$ given by $M_{ij} = a_j^i$ has non-zero determinant, I am having issues.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you! (=

[This is part of a past paper exam question - it doesn't explicitly ask me to do this, but this is part of the method that I am using. The above must be a basis because the required result implies that it is a basis - shame I can't use the answer to prove itself =P!]

Comment: [Lagrange polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) do the trick here

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix would that help ?

Comment: If $\phi_j\in V^*$ then shouldn't $\phi_j:V^*\to \Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Should have thought of that! Thanks. Would you use the fact that any polynomial of degree $n$ can be written uniquely as a sum of the $n+1$ Lagrange polys?

Comment: @ellya formally yes, but since $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic, up to a transformation you can "remove" or not any star you want

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Thank you - that is the exact matrix that I want (well, the transpose of it, but the determinant is the important part). Since it has it's own name, is it difficult to show the result?

Comment: @ellya - Yes, my mistake. I didn't actually say, but the $a_i$ are real. I'll update the question.

Comment: @SmileySam: Exactly. Or, in other words, they form a basis of $V$. Working in that basis your problem becomes way easier.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui but wouldnt $\phi_j(a_j)$ just give us scalar values? I dont see how we would make any $n$th order polynomial? Am I missing something?

Comment: @SmileySam not really, actually the shorter proof is to write down the equation $MX=0$, and it is almost the same than your problem, you have something like $\sum \nu_j a_r^j = 0$ (since this is the transpose), and you see that the polynomial $P=\sum \nu_j X^j$ has $n+1$ roots while of degree at most $n$, so it's null, and so are the coefficient $\nu_j$

Comment: wait I apologise, I though it said that $\{\phi_1,...,\phi_n\}$ forms a basis on $V$ rather than $V^*$

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Ah, so when you take the transpose, you "swap the indices and the power" - this then gives the polynomial with $n+1$ roots.

Comment: @ellya ooups sorry, you were right actually, $V$ is a space of polynomials, my bad !

Comment: @SmileySam yes, exactly. I thought it could be also done directly with your equations, but it seems not and using the transpose appears to be an actually useful trick to make it appear

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! I'm just going through the Lagrange method first, then I'll do it with the transpose also (will impress my supervisor ;)! - should really tell him that I had help though...)